# Is it possible to put image mid of the list item in minipage?

Tags: lists, minipage

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
  \begin{enumerate}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
    \item De la proposición anterior se deduce inmediatamente que los afijos de las raíces $n$-ésimas de un número complejo no nulo son los vértices de un polígono regular de $n$ lados centrado en el origen.
  
    \item El cuerpo  fue ampliado a  con la condición de que la ecuación $x^2+1=0$ tuviera alguna solución. Pero en , tal y como deja entrever la proposición anterior, no sólo la ecuación anterior tiene soluciones sino que, según establece el Teorema Fundamental del Álgebra, cualquier polinomio complejo no constante tiene alguna raíz compleja. La primera demostración conocida de este teorema se debe a Gauss.
\end{enumerate}\end{minipage}\hfill
 \noindent  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
 \includegraphics[width=7.0cm]{C9_Fig6.png}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to put image in side and mid of the list items.]

Comment: Hmm... I reformatted your post, but I think you posted a code that does not correspond to the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, than you after something like this:

[image]

This can be simple to achieve with small changes in your MWE:

- remove `t` (top) options for vertical positioning  of `minipage`s and use default settings  (which is vertical centered)
- remove all hackeray for move image baseline

and some off-topic changes:

- added is `enumitem` package for simple customizing of lists
- added is `microtype` package for better formation of text

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}  % added, for better text spacing

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % added

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}               % changed position and width
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item De la proposición anterior se deduce inmediatamente que los afijos de las raíces $n$-ésimas de un número complejo no nulo son los vértices de un polígono regular de $n$ lados centrado en el origen.
    \item El cuerpo  fue ampliado a  con la condición de que la ecuación $x^2+1=0$ tuviera alguna solución. Pero en , tal y como deja entrever la proposición anterior, no sólo la ecuación anterior tiene soluciones sino que, según establece el Teorema Fundamental del Álgebra, cualquier polinomio complejo no constante tiene alguna raíz compleja. La primera demostración conocida de este teorema se debe a Gauss.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}    % changed position and width
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```